# CSS file for poster made with Rmarkdown: need font

Tags: css, r-markdown

this is very much a rookie question.

I am trying to make a poster for some research results. I am playing around with posterdown, the template/package made by [Brent Thorne](https://github.com/brentthorne/posterdown/wiki). I can't seem to fix the font in the header.

[image: I want to be able to change that top font]

My (very limited) CSS file is as below:

```
/* Whole document: */

body{
    font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
    font-size: 16pt; 
}

/* Headers: */
h1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: NavyBlue;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 18 pt;
    color: LightBlue; 
}
```

I assumed that I would be able to change the font family, size etc under "h1" but that is not the case.

Comment: Isn't it controlled in YAML with `main_fontfamily`?
https://github.com/brentthorne/posterdown/wiki/posterdown_betterport